# Sync svn and mercurial repo

Tags: svn, mercurial, hgsubversion, mercurial-convert

We have an active svn repository and we are planning a migration to mercurial. The idea is to create a new mercurial repo, sync the svn repo with it with history, create a teamcity build for it and move two developers onto mercurial solely to trial it out and make sure its all kosher.

This means we need bi-directional sync between svn and mercurial. I have seen this link [Syncing SVN to Mercurial using svnsync & hg convert -- misses svn:externals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258518/syncing-svn-to-mercurial-using-svnsync-hg-convert-misses-svnexternals) which sort of describes a way but it is fairly clunky and manual.

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you try to use **only** the [HgSubversion](https://bitbucket.org/durin42/hgsubversion/overview) plugin for Mercurial.

There is a reference for it in the [Mercurial  wiki](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/HgSubversion).

The process is simple, install the plugin, then use Mercurial to clone from  Subversion. After that, you can use HG commands to synchronize from/to the SVN repository.

Comment: Just following up to say this works very nicely, thanks again!